# python setup.py install ignores install_requires

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I am unable to install the local packages using `setup.py`

Here is the project structure:

```
my-project/
  lib/
     local1/
        local1.1.0.whl
        index.html
     local2/
        local2.1.0.whl
        index.html
  setup.py
```

*setup.py*

```
import os

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='my project',
      version='1.0',
      description='my project',
      install_requires=[
        'lxml >= 4.3.0',
        'local1 @ file://localhost/{}/lib/local1/local1.1.0.whl'.format(os.getcwd()),
        'local2 @ file://localhost/{}/lib/local2/local2.2.0.whl'.format(os.getcwd()),
      ]
      )
```

I can install if I put the dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file and use `pip install -r requirements.txt --extra-index-url lib/`, but I want to know why is it not possible to do `python setup.py install` or if I am missing something.

This is the error that I get -

```
No local packages or working download links found for local2@ file://localhost//Users/anusha/Documents/my-project/lib/local2/local2.1.0.whl
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('local2@ file://localhost//Users/anusha/Documents/my-project/lib/local2/local2.1.0.whl')
```

On searching, I found this issue on [github](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/456), but does not give me any pointers or solution as to how it worked.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure _setuptools_ supports this notation. Are you referring to ["direct references" of _PEP440_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references)? Note the three (3) slashes!

Comment: since I am specifying `localhost` 2 slashes should suffice, even I am not sure of setuptools supporting this, but did not find any supporting documents for proving this!
I tried `pip install git+file//$PWD/` and it seemed to work

Comment: Yes, in between I read the ["File URLs" section of _PEP 440_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#file-urls) that seems to specify this notation and thus support your claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note this [comment from *pganssle* in the discussion "Setuptools install fails with PEP508 URLs" in *setuptools*'s issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1983#issuecomment-584130062):

> Our policy to date has been that if using `pip install` fixes your problem, you should use `pip install` and we won't fix the issue.

I believe this is in line with the current evolution of the packaging tools and techniques in the Python community. So if your *setuptools*-based project with this requirement notation can be installed via `pip install .` and `pip install --editable .`, then look no further.

---

A more complete (exhaustive) article on the topic:

- [Paul Ganssle's "*Why you shouldn't invoke setup.py directly*"](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html)

Comment: Thanks! enough evidence to not get hung up on `python setup.py install`

Comment: The OP only said `pip install -r requirements` works, whicih doesn't use setup.py at all, as opposed to `pip install .` I currently have this problem and `pip install .` doesn't work to install packages at install_requires. install_requires and requirements.txt serve different functions.

Comment: @joshuam I do not understand what is your point. If you have a new (and unique) question, feel free to ask it as a new question (not as a comment).