# How to install git+https:// from setup.py using install_requires

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a project in which I have to install from git+https:

I can make it to work in this way:

```
virtualenv -p python3.5 bla
. bla/bin/activate
pip install numpy # must have numpy before the following pkg...
pip install 'git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI'
```

However, I want to use it in a setup.py file in `install_requires`:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(install_requires='git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI', setup_requires='numpy')
```

and then, `pip install -e .` from the dir containing the `setup.py`

This doesn't work due to parse error:

```
    Complete output (1 lines):                                                                                                             
    error in bla_bla setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requireme
nt specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+https:/'"                                                                             
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The error doesn't occur if I install using `pip install -r requires.txt` (assuming I have the same string in that file) and not when using direct `pip install git+...`...

How to fix this parsing error?

What I've tried so far:

1. wrapping the string with " / """ / ' / '''
2. adding 'r' before the string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write setup.py to include a git repo as a dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688688/how-to-write-setup-py-to-include-a-git-repo-as-a-dependency)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60370913/11138259

Comment: @BramVanroy `dependency_links` were declared obsolete and finally [removed](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) in `pip` 19.0. Please retract your vote.

Comment: @phd It's the same core question, though, and answers on the duplicate question also answer this one (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54794506/1150683).

Comment: @BramVanroy 4 out of 5 answers there mention `dependency_links`. The answers are outdated and should not be pointed at.

Comment: @phd Updated this question to be specific about install_requires to better distinguish the questions and retracted my vote.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`install_requires` must be a string or a list of strings with names and optionally URLs to get the package from:

```
install_requires=[
    'pycocotools @ git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI'
]
```

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirement-specifiers/ and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references

This requires `pip install` including `pip install .` and doesn't work with `python setup.py install`.

Comment: I'll add this reference for the `python setup.py install` vs. `pip install .` part: [comment from _pganssle_ in the discussion "Setuptools install fails with PEP508 URLs" in _setuptools_'s issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1983#issuecomment-584130062): "_Our policy to date has been that if using `pip install` fixes your problem, you should use `pip install` and we won't fix the issue_"

Comment: That sucks, because there is an inconsistency between `pip install "pkg_name" / pip install -r <requirements_file>` and `pip install -e .`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ClsForCookies What is the inconsistency? I believe if all the requirements follow _PEP 508_ and `setup.py` is not called directly then it should be consistent.

Comment: Can you tell what role does this part play in the command? `#subdirectory=PythonAPI`