# Specify version for private git repos in setup.py

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

How can I specify a version for private repos in my setup.py file so that only this version is used?

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
   name="my_module"
   version="1.0.4"
   install_requires=[
    "requests==2.20.0",
    "test @ git+ssh://git@xxxx/xxxxx/test.git",
   ],
   // etc. 
)
```

Does my test git project have to have any properties so that I can read out the version? At the moment I only use the version field in setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup
setup(
  name="test",
  version="0.5.1",
  //etc.
)
```

Comment: Let it point to a specific _git tag_.

Comment: you mean: git tag -a v$(python setup.py --version) -m '0.5.1' ? and how can I specify the tag in the setup.py? Moreover whats the purpose of the version field in the setup.py file?

Comment: The `version` argument to `setuptools.setup` is used to set the _version_ metadata field in the distributions (_sdist_, _wheel_) of the project. So it's meaningful if the distributions of the project are published on an index (such as _PyPI_) and the project is installed directly from there. When the project is installed from _git_, it's different, there are no distributions in the git repository, so there is no metadata immediately available, not until **after** the repository has been cloned at least. So point at a git _tag_ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure, but if I am not mistaken in `install_requires` you could have something like the following:

`MyProject @ git://git.example.com/MyProject.git@v1.0`

When the project has to be installed from a *git* repository (or other code versioning systems) you can't really point at a version number like you can when the project is hosted on an index (such as *PyPI*), but the next best thing is that you can point at a specific *git tag* (or a *branch*, or any other kind of similar reference, but *tag* is probably the best choice for this use case).

Also, I might be wrong, but this notation might not be supported by pure *setuptools*. This means you most likely won't be able to use `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py install`, but should use `python -m pip install -e .` or `python -m pip install .` instead.

References:

- https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/
- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#direct-references
- https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1983#issuecomment-584130062
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60372954/11138259