# Private Git Repo in setup.py install_requires

Tags: python, git

I want pip to install a package "my_tools" from a private github repo whenever a package called "my_utils" is to be installed.

My setup.py:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my_utils",
    version="1.0",
    description="Common utility tools",
    author="author",
    packages=['my_utils'],
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.6",
    install_requires=[
        'pandas',
        'requests',
        'my_tools@git+ssh://git@github.company.com/org/My_Tools.git@2.0'
    ],
    dependency_links=['git+ssh://git@github.company.com/org/My_Tools.git@2.0']
)
```

I run: `pip install -e .` and get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas ....
Requirement already satisfied: requests ....
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-tools (unavailable) (from my-utils) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for my-tools (unavailable)
```

None of these answers worked: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701434/5289570), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60673180/5289570), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393849/5289570)

EDIT: I've also tried the following, but still not working:

```
install_requires=[
    'my_tools @ git+ssh://git@github.company.com/org/My_Tools.git@2.0'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using http link instead of ssh?

```
git+http://git@github.company.com/org/My_Tools.git@2.0
```

Comment: This should just be a comment to the OP rather than a question as an answer.

Comment: SSH is best practice for my company. Also when I try a `git+https://...` url, it prompts me to log in, which succeeds, but results in the same error.